# Why is my memory footprint growing?

Tags: c++, ios, memory-leaks, openframeworks

The following example makes use of the openFrameworks toolkit, but I guess my error is not openFrameworks specific so I hope someone can help.

I use ofxThreadedImageLoader to dynamically load images. And I use another thread to unload/delete. I have condensed my problem into a little piece of code. I don't need the delete-thread in this example but I do need it in my real program, so that's why it's in here. (Also if I delete in the main loop instead of the thread, I don't get the problem. With the thread it's like the images are getting copied somewhere and only one copy gets deleted.)

```
void testApp::setup(){  
alreadyLoaded = false;
tmpImage = new ofImage();

loader.loadFromDisk(tmpImage, "images/test.png");
loader.startThread(true, false);
imageDeleter.start();

}


void testApp::update(){
bool alreadyLoaded = tmpImage->isUsingTexture();

if(alreadyLoaded) {
    ofTexture& tex = tmpImage->getTextureReference();
    alreadyLoaded = tex.bAllocated();
}

if(alreadyLoaded) { 
    imageDeleter.addImageToDelete(tmpImage);

    tmpImage = new ofImage();
    int nImages = DIR.listDir("images/");

    loader.loadFromDisk(tmpImage, DIR.getPath((int) ofRandom(nImages)));
}
}
```

Update is the programs main loop. Here's the threaded delete:

```
class threadedDelete : public ofxThread{

public:
deque<ofImage *> images_to_delete;

//--------------------------
threadedDelete() {

}


threadedDelete(ofImage*  _imageToDelete){
    lock();
    images_to_delete.push_back(_imageToDelete);
    unlock();
}


void addImageToDelete(ofImage*  _imageToDelete) {
    lock();
    images_to_delete.push_back(_imageToDelete);
    unlock();
}

void start(){
    startThread(true, false);   // blocking, verbose
}

void stop(){
    stopThread();
}

//--------------------------
void threadedFunction(){
    while(isThreadRunning()){
        if (images_to_delete.size() > 0) {
            lock();

            ofImage  * imageToDelete(images_to_delete.front());
            ofLog(OF_LOG_NOTICE, "deleting " + ofToString(imageToDelete)); 
            images_to_delete.pop_front();
            delete imageToDelete;

            unlock();
        }
        else {
            ofSleepMillis(50);
        }
    }
}

};
```

So basically I'm just loading a random image and when it's loaded, I delete it and load another one. Even though every new ofImage gets deleted, my memory footprint grows until I get a memory warning (iOS) and my app crashes. What do I miss?
As I said I know the code is using openFrameworks classes but I guess my error is pretty basic so someone might be able to see it based on this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This is why [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is created. Make sure you compile your application with debug symbols (`-g` for g++, for example) and run:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./your_program --args --to --your program
```